# Amazon Machine Image(AMI) for PHP5

Tags: php, linux, memcached, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to move my application on EC2.
I would like to know the AMI Image which has Linux(Preferably Ubuntu),PHP 5,MemCached, eAccelerator or XCache.

Please advise.

Regards,
Mugil.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to create your own AMI. 
You can make use the community tested Ubuntu AMI's found at http://www.alestic.com.
The process is launch, install packages, (bundle/upload) and register.

Make sure you use EBS or S3 to persists your data.

Cheers,

Rodney

http://www.capsunlock.net